# Keeping inline-div on same line as text

Tags: html, css

I have a small icon on at the end of a short paragraph of text, which may wrap over multiple lines depending on the viewport size. It's important to me that this icon not occupy an empty line by itself, but rather carry the last word of the paragraph with it. Is there any way to ensure this with pure css?

I considered dynamically grouping the last word of the paragraph with the icon in an inline block. I would prefer to not have to use javascript though, if possible.

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/09xjcm4g/2/) jsfiddle displays the undesired behavior.

```
    <div class="resizable">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
    <div class="inlineblock"> </div>
    </div>
```

```
    .resizable {
      border: 1px solid black;
      resize: both;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 11.5rem;
    }

    .inlineblock {
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      background-color: blue;
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

Comment: This is how far I get: https://jsfiddle.net/wu6ca3om/ .

Answer (score 2):

You could use ::after to place the block

```css
.resizable {
  border: 1px solid black;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 11.5rem;
}

.content {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  font-size: 18px; /* specify font size for better result */
  line-height: 18px; /* specify line height for better result */
}

.content::after {
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: -10px;
  position: relative;
  left: 3px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle; /* adjust vertical alignment with text */
}
```

```html
<div class="resizable">
<span class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is something I considered. However, the icon needs to trigger a javascript event when clicked, and so I believe it can't be a pseudo-element.

Answer (score 1):

Change the html a bit by wrapping `.inlineblock` and the last word in `<span>` which will have `white-space: nowrap;`:

```css
.resizable {
  border: 1px solid black;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 11.5rem;
}

.nowrap{
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.inlineblock {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="resizable">
  <span>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    <span class="nowrap">amet <span class="inlineblock"></span></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

As you have mentioned in a comment that the block should be clickable and trigger an event so I have written the following code for you. Here I have used anchor tag on purpose. But you can use a span as well.

```js
function showMe() {
  document.getElementById("hidden-item").style.display="block";
}
```

```css
.resizable {
  border: 1px solid black;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 11.5rem;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.resizable span::after {
  content: " ";
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.inlineblock {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#hidden-item {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="resizable">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span><a class="inlineblock" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showMe()"></a>
</div>
<div id="hidden-item">Hello World!</div>
```